# A little help in asp.net C# jumping from method to method

Tags: c#, asp.net

My problem is that I can get from page_load to show_books function
but I cant get from show_books to book_detail.
Every time I try to fire book_details it gets me to page_load.

my code is this:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Here I create dynamic linkbuttons that calls datashow
       lnk_button.Command += new CommandEventHandler(book_show);
    }
    protected void book_show(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Here I show all books from a category
        //and I create dynamic linkbuttons that calls book_details
        book_button.Command += new CommandEventHandler(book_details);
    }

    protected void book_details(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //and Here I show the details of each book 
    }
```

I'm sorry if my question is annoyingly newbie
but I would like some help .
I just started to learn asp.net

Comment: chage access modifer from protected to public.

Comment: you mean to change book_details from protected to public?

Comment: Page_Load occurs because you obviously do a full page postback. But what caught my eye is the comment that you create dynamic linkbuttons. Maybe you can show the code how you generate it? Do you assign IDs to the dynamically generated controls?

Answer (score 0):

well i don't understand why you need to do this,but code below works,hope it helps

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Here I create dynamic linkbuttons that calls datashow
    lnk_button.Command += new CommandEventHandler(this.book_show);
    lnk_button.CommandName = "testClick";
    lnk_button.CommandArgument = "1";
    lnk_button.ID = "11";
    lnk_button.Text = "blah";

    book_button.Command += new CommandEventHandler(this.book_details);
    book_button.CommandName = "testClick2";
    book_button.CommandArgument = "2";
    book_button.ID = "22";
    book_button.Text = "blah2";
}

protected void book_show(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Here I show all books from a category
    //and I create dynamic linkbuttons that calls book_details
    book_button.Command += new CommandEventHandler(this.book_details);
    book_button.CommandName = "testClick2";
    book_button.CommandArgument = "2";
    book_button.ID = "22";
    book_button.Text = "blah2";
}

protected void book_details(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //and Here I show the details of each book 
}
```

Comment: Thnx very much but we can get easily from page_load to book_show method. But how can we can get from book_show method to anyother method since linkbuttons get us again in page load?

Comment: please try the code,by that code,lnk_button's clicking jumps to book_show function and book_button's clicking jumps to book_details function

Answer (score -1):

```
     public void book_show()
   {
        book_details() ;
    } 


     public void book_details()
    {

     }
```

Comment: same thing. Everytime I click a button that fires book_details() it gets me to page_load

Comment: yes it will happen bcos buttons click event refreshes the page so page gets loaded everytime when u click a button.

Comment: but why when I click a linkbutton from page_load it gets me normally to book_show?

Comment: can anyone help plz? I am really stack here